# Webscraping in R not showing nodes

Tags: html, r, rest, web-scraping

I'm trying to get a list of all the articles and prices from this [website](https://www.pedidosya.com.do/restaurantes/santo-domingo-d-n/supermercados-bravo-menu) using rvest. It is a fairly simple task, but I keep getting an empty list.

So far I have used the code bellow with no avail.

Is there something that I'm missing or doing wrong?

```
url <- c("https://www.pedidosya.com.do/restaurantes/santo-domingo-d-n/supermercados-bravo-menu")

articulo <- read_html(url) %>% 
  html_nodes('.shelves_product_name') %>% 
  html_attrs()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webpage you are trying to scrape is dynamic and so you will need to use a package like RSelenium.

The below code should work:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
    
url <- c("https://www.pedidosya.com.do/restaurantes/santo-domingo-d-n/supermercados-bravo-menu")

rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome")
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

remDr$navigate(url)
pg <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])

 product_name <- pg %>% html_nodes(".shelves_product_name") %>% html_text()
 product_price <- pg %>% html_nodes(".price") %>% html_text() %>%
   str_remove_all("\n") %>%
   str_squish()
  
df <- data.frame(Name = product_name, Price = product_price)

remDr$close()
rD$server$stop()
rm(rD, remDr)
gc()

system("taskkill /im java.exe /f", intern=FALSE, ignore.stdout=FALSE)
```

Comment: Excelente. I had no idea dynamic websites were a thing. Now I'm doing some research on RSelenium to broaden my knowledge. Thank you, mr Blue, you have helped me a lot.